# Apache on Raspberry Pi - can't serve files from a different drive - causes 403 error

Tags: linux, apache, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I got a Raspberry Pi yesterday and have mounted an additional hard drive on it. I'm planning to use it on a web server. However, I wish to host my files on the hard drive, not the small SD card where the OS is located.

I installed Apache and created a Virtual Host config file, specifying the DocumentRoot and the directory on the external HDD where the website is located. However, it gives a 403 error. The system log gives the following information:

```
Permission denied: [client 123.456.789.1250527] AH00035: access to / denied (filesystem path '/media/myusername/myHDD') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path
```

I've tried a number of different things: setting the DocumentRoot to /var/www/html but specifying the path to the HDD in the Directory tag, changing the DocumentRoot in the default site to the path to the HDD's directory that I want to serve, adding the line DocumentRoot "/media/myusername/myHDD" in the apache2.conf file. I changed the ownership of the /myHDD folder to the www-data user. I eventually deleted the /var/www/html folder and created a symlink to the HDD's directory with the name `html`, but that causeed this error:

```
AH00037: Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /var/www/html
```

What do I need to do to make Apache serve these websites that are on the HDD and not the system SD (only 16GB)? Here is my VirtualHost config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin me@myemail.com
ServerName myurl.com
ServerAlias www.myurl.com

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
Alias "/webals" "/media/userName/MyHardDrive/public_html/myurl.com/"

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
<Directory "/media/userName/MyHardDrive/public_html/myurl.com">
    Require all granted
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I'm not sure what is going on here. Haven't really used Apache much in the past - have preferred nginx.

Any help here would be good.

Comment: Have you checked if this is due to selinux?

Comment: It seems selinux is disabled on raspbian, maybe your folder permissions are the issue? https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/38772/apache-permission-denied